# Can gdb print the contents of the buffer written to by the C write() function?

Tags: c, shell, gdb, pipe

I have the following code:

```
write(fd[1], user_id, sizeof(user_id));
```

Is it possible to use gdb to see the contents of the buffer written to by this command?
Using x or print just gives the memory address, not the contents of the buffer in that address.

```
(gdb) x write
0x7ffff7af4140 <__GI___libc_write>: 0xb1058d48
```

Since the fd[1] refers to stdout, this request should be equivalent to checking the status of the stdout buffer.

Additional info:
user_id is a char array. fd[1] means write is writing to stdout (fd[0] refers to stdin).
This is line 44 of a program, and I am accessing it with a breakpoint.

Comment: You want to see `user_id`? Which command are you using? Please add this information and the output to the question

Comment: added some clarification

Comment: Regarding the latest edits, what buffer do you mean?  In the terminology of the `read()` and `write()` functions, the "buffer" *is* `user_id` in this case.  File descriptors do not have an associated data buffer, or at least not a documented one.

Comment: I see. I would like to see the buffer of the file descriptor, in this case it points to stdout, so the buffer of stdout. 

(The root problem for which I am debugging is I am producing 2 write calls in a row, and 2 read calls in a separate file, yet for some reason only one transaction, not 2, occur - the first write call is recorded by the first read. The second read doesn't take any input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be such a GDB functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Let suppose you are interested in a variable `user_id` which is present at line `44` of file `myfile.c` of a program `myprogram`

```
write(fd[1], user_id, sizeof(user_id)); //line 44 of myfile.c
```

You must execute this :

```
gdb myprogram
```

Set breakpoint in gdb:

```
b myfile.c:44
```

Run program (After this command the breakpoint will be reached):

```
run
```

Print your variable value:

```
p user_id
```

Comment: Or one could use a variety of other means to run the program in `gdb` up to the point of the `write()` call of interest.  It doesn't have to specifically be a breakpoint on that line, though that will definitely work.

Comment: I note, however, that the OP may mean something different by "what was actually written" than what data were passed to `write()`.  For instance, they may be hoping to confirm that `write()` actually behaves as it is specified to do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I agree, but as he mentioned the content aspect and he presents only  the address of the varibal, I think he is interested in its content

Comment: That's not exactly it. I would like to print the result of the write call - i.e. see what is actually going into the buffer of stdout as a result of the call.
I'll edit my post to make that clearer

Comment: @Cheetaiean You can start by capturing the value returned by write ( it returns the number of bytes written (0 means no writing), or -1 if it fails)

Comment: So I guess there is no gdb functionality for that. Thanks for the tip though, it is a good step in the right direction.